# How to update gridview with new images

Tags: android, gridview, xamarin

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imagelist, imageBool, resourceName, docBool);
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            //gridview.Adapter = null;
            gridview.InvalidateViews();
            gridview.Adapter = adapter;
```

I send the list with the new values to the imageadapter and it sorts the values out and returnes the items as images and alls is good. But when i want to refresh the items the old ones just stays the same and the new ones never arrives on the screen. Ive tried a lot of different ways to reload the grid but it doesn't work.

Comment: you must call notifydatasetchanged() on adapter to display new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following methods to your customized adapter ie. `ImageAdapter`.

```
// Call it once , first time when you want to pass the data to adapter 
public void setImageList(List<YOUR DATA TYPE> imagelist) {
    this.imagelist = imagelist;
}

// Call this method whenever new data is to be added to existing list.
public void updateImageList(List<YOUR DATA TYPE> newImagelist) {  

    if(this.imagelist != null){
       this.imagelist.addAll(newImagelist);
    }else{
       this.imagelist = imagelist;
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And call it once the new data is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new ImageAdapter with all the Images (including the old ones and the new ones) and assign it to the gridview. This way it works without problems.
After that call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imagelist, imageBool, resourceName, docBool);
                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                gridview.Adapter = adapter;
                adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

If this is what you meant it didn't work :(

Comment: Use gridview.setAdapter(adapter); to set the adapter. I have some sample code here and it looks like this:
adapter = new ImageAdapter(activity, employees, department, letter);
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Probably it will work now.